# passwordless login set up automation for ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

I have space separated file containing ip addresses and credentials like this:

```
10.0.0.1 user_master password_master
10.0.0.3 user_slave1 password_slave1
...
10.0.0.20 user_slave20 password_slave20
```

I want create mutual passwordless ssh login between master(first line) and all other slaves. All machines are new Ubuntu 14.04 with no `openssh-server` installed.

Right now I am able to use `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` to create public key login without inputing password one by one manually, but it's tedious when there are many machines.

I want to know how to write script to automate this process. I find it hard for me especially when I have to pass credentials after ssh to other machine then exit.

Or is there a out-of-box tool designed for this automation task?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple bash script ex: `upload.sh` and write some automation script :

```
#!/bin/bash

remote_host=(192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 172.90.44.21)

for i in "${remote_host[@]}"
do
    echo Uploading SSH Key to Host : $i
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $i
done
```

You can input your remote address on `remote_host` array
Make it executable

```
chmod upload.sh
```

and then, execute it

```
./upload.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want create mutual ssh passwordless login but this only gives a one way login

Comment: Do you want to create ssh connection between each host, like this?

Host1 to Host 2
          to Host 3
          to Host 4

Host 2 to Host1
           to Host3
           to Host4
...........

Comment: I want just one to many relation, but the relation is mutual, like Host1 to host2,3,4, and host2 to host1, host3 to host1, host4 to host1.